# Onetime login is not working and second time also showing LoginActivity in android

Tags: android, authentication

Hi in the below code I was implemented ontime login feature but it is not working with below code.If login is successful then it will redirecting to MainActivity.Next time want to skip login page directly it should show main activity.

SplashActivity.java:

```
final boolean needLogin = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("need login extra", true);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                if(!needLogin) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        },
```

Once the login is successfull it will redirect to MAninactivity.java.Entire app I am using session.

LoginActivity.java:

```
           if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                                            LoginAndFetchModules loginAndFetchModules = response.body();


                                            String success = loginAndFetchModules.getSuccess();

                                            if (success.equals("true")) {
                                                Results results = loginAndFetchModules.getResult();


                                                //parse login details
                                                GetLoginListDetails loginDetails = results.getLogin();
                                                String userId = loginDetails.getUserid();
                                                String sessionId = loginDetails.getSession();
                                                String firstname = loginDetails.getFirst_name();
                                                String lastname = loginDetails.getLast_name();
                                                String mobile = loginDetails.getMobile();
                                                String role = loginDetails.getRole();
                                                String reportto = loginDetails.getReportto();

                                                //parse modules
                                                ArrayList<LoginListForModules> modules = results.getModules();

                                                //parse module information
                                                for (LoginListForModules module : modules) {
                                                    module_id = module.getId();
                                                    String name = module.getName();
                                                    String isEntity = module.getIsEntity();
                                                    String label = module.getLabel();
                                                    String singular = module.getSingular();
                                                }


                                                if (username.equals(username1.getText().toString()) && password.equals(password1.getText().toString())) {


                                                    //  fetchUserJSON(sessionId,username);
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    // loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    //  llProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                    i.putExtra("sessionId", sessionId);
                                                    i.putExtra("module_id", module_id);
                                                    i.putExtra("username", username);
                                                    i.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
                                                    i.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
                                                    i.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
                                                    i.putExtra("role", role);
                                                    i.putExtra("reportto", reportto);


                                                    startActivity(i);
                                                    finish();
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }

                                        }
```

Comment: where you are setting need login extra to true ? I.e after login post that code also

Comment: You need to implement Shared Preferences in Android, for storing the information regarding the login Boolean value, Please have a look at this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjXlFkBWJCY

Comment: @PraveenSP please have a look

Comment: Wait is this SplashActivity is launcher activity ? Or is there any other activity before it ?

Comment: @PraveenSP yes Splash is launcher activity

Comment: Then in that case final boolean needLogin = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("need login extra", true);  will be  always true ....

Comment: In LoginAcivity Iadded final boolean needLogin = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("need login extra", false); it is correct

Comment: @PraveenSP Just now updated

Comment: @jyothichandra Kindly check my logic. Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`SharedPreferences`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

> A SharedPreferences object points to a file containing key-value
>   pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them.

**DEMO CODE**

```
public class SharedPreferenceClass
 {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Test";

    public static final String KEY_SET_LOGIN_STATUS= "KEY_SET_LOGIN_STATUS";

    public SharedPreferenceClass(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void setLoginStatus(String status)
    {
        editor.remove(KEY_SET_LOGIN_STATUS);
        editor.putString(KEY_SET_LOGIN_STATUS, status);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getLoginStatus()
    {
        String status= pref.getString(KEY_SET_LOGIN_STATUS, "");
        return status;
    }

 }
```

Now you can store login status ( setLoginStatus("Login")) when ever login success And check your login status  getLoginStatus(). If return "Login" then return to your desire activity.